# Question about Hessian matrix and its application to find maximum

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

If I have a function $f(x.y)=x^2+xy$

And I want to find out maximum, minimum or saddle points.

If I find out Hessian matrix, entries of this matrix is constant.

Then, it seems like that we can not use hessian matrix test to find out extremum points.?

Is that right?

even though stationary points exists.

Comment: What makes you say a constant Hessian cannot be used to classify extrema?

Comment: When we use hessian matrix to determine extrema, we have to consider hessian matrix at stationary points. But, if hessian matrix is itself a constant, there is no way to plug in stationary points...?

Comment: The second derivative of $f(x)=x^2$ is constant as well; do you think it doesn't tell you about what happens at the stationary point? It doesn't matter that the Hessian is constant: it makes things even easier, since you don't have any further calculation to do.

Answer (score 0):

The hessian of this function will be $$H=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1/2\\
1/2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$Clearly the matrix is not positive definite (as corrected by @dawg in the comment) the eigenvalues being $1/2(1\pm\sqrt{2})$. So the stationary point $(0,0)$ that you get from the first order condition, is a saddle point.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it should be the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

This function has one stationary point: $(x,y)=0$. The Hessian is given by
$$
\nabla^2 f = \pmatrix{ 2& 1\\1&0}.
$$
Its eigenvalues are $1\pm \sqrt2$, thus the Hessian is indefinit. Hence the stationary point is a saddle point.